# Select from dynamically created imageviews

Tags: android

I have generated dynamically ImageView's in LinearLayout - let's say 6, with backgrounds and images, so they are looking like an icons. 
Now I would like to select one and based on this which icon is selected proceed with other things. 
I know that I can set onClickListener for dynamically create ImageView's.

but question is, how to select one? with jQUery I would add some class after tapping on an icon, in Android ? I really do know, tried something with setTag() but, well, did not happened.

Assuming that somehow I know which icon was tapped, then how can I loop through all dynamic generated ImageView's to get selected one?

Comment: What was wrong with setOnClickListener? I'd go with this one. You'll get the view in the callback method, then just check if view == your imageview.

Comment: well I get that but I have no idea to manage this bit with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say in a loop you are creating the ImageView's and adding that to the LinearLayout. Assign a onClickListener to all the ImageViews. Just like the following code.

```
    yourImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView selectedImageView = (ImageView) v;
            // selectedImageView is the imageView which you have selected

        }
    });
```

So when you tap on a imageView, its onClick function will be called. Parameter passed to the onClick function will be the imageView which you have selected. Just typeCast the View 'v' to ImageView and use in your application.

Comment: thanks for this, obviously I do understand that, now problem is, how  can I get this selected View in different onClick method, well even in different class? I thought that process should be like 
onClick imageView - setTag or similar saying that this one is selected
another onClick - loop over all ImagesView find one by tag

Comment: Did I answer to your question? I mean you got the solution to your problem now?

Comment: ya.. Thats one solution. Instead of that , you can save the selected imageView in a variable and make that view 'selectedImageView' global variable in your class , so that you can access that variable from other class.

Comment: well is that safe? you know what they say about global variables,

Comment: If you want to avoid using global variable then use private variable itself and create a global function inside activity which return the selected ImageView which is private.